# golang alpine docker Cross compile C++

Tags: c++, docker, go

I have a golang project that relies on C for invocation and compilation. Now, I used the `make all` command to build in the docker image of golang:alpine and found the following error：

```sh
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/git.ipyker.com/combase/gowork@v0.0.0-20191008073240-ec01ac359684/src/py/cgo/3party/protobuf/libprotobuf.a(structurally_valid.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
```

C is introduced in the golang project, I have set the -fPIE parameter in LDFLAGS。

```sh
package l5

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -fPIE -L./lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lqos_client -Wl,-Bdynamic -lstdc++
#include "qos_client_c.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
*/
import "C"
```

The contents of the Makefile are as follows:

```
VERSION = "2.1"
COMMIT = $(shell git rev-parse --short HEAD)
XCFS_AS = ./bin/xcfs_as
XCFS_FS = ./bin/xcfs_fs
XCFS_FA = ./bin/xcfs_handlefail

all : $(XCFS_AS) $(XCFS_FS) $(XCFS_FA)
$(XCFS_AS) : $(shell find ./pkg/ ./cmd/xcfs_as/ -name "*.go")
        go build -o $@ -ldflags "-X main.version=$(VERSION) -X main.commit=$(COMMIT)" ./cmd/xcfs_as/

$(XCFS_FS) : $(shell find ./pkg/ ./cmd/xcfs_fs/ -name "*.go")
        go build -o $@ -ldflags "-X main.version=$(VERSION) -X main.commit=$(COMMIT)" ./cmd/xcfs_fs/

$(XCFS_FA) : $(shell find ./pkg/ ./cmd/xcfs_handlefail/ -name "*.go")
        go vet ./cmd/xcfs_handlefail/
        go build -o $@ -ldflags "-X main.version=$(VERSION) -X main.commit=$(COMMIT)" ./cmd/xcfs_handlefail/
test :

vet :
        go vet ./cmd/xcfs_as/
        go vet ./cmd/xcfs_fs/
        go vet ./cmd/xcfs_handlefail/

clean :
        @rm -f ./bin/*
```

and I also performed the following operations on the golang:alpine mirror:

```sh
apk add gcc g++ cmake make
wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub
wget https://reg.ipyker.com/artifactory/package-local/alpine-pkg-glibc/2.29-r0/glibc-2.29-r0.apk
wget https://reg.ipyker.com/artifactory/package-local/alpine-pkg-glibc/2.29-r0/glibc-bin-2.29-r0.apk
wget https://reg.ipyker.com/artifactory/package-local/alpine-pkg-glibc/2.29-r0/glibc-i18n-2.29-r0.apk
apk add --no-cache glibc-2.29-r0.apk glibc-bin-2.29-r0.apk glibc-i18n-2.29-r0.apk
apk add --no-cache build-base curl automake autoconf libtool git zlib-dev
apk add --no-cache protoc libprotoc libprotobuf-lite libprotobuf
wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/armhf/protobuf-3.12.2-r0.apk
apk add protobuf-3.12.2-r0.apk
```

The result is still the same error, unresolved。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling shared libraries is broken with -no-pie, which should be a noop in this case.

```sh
go env -w CC="gcc -no-pie"
```